# scipy.optimize.minimize two different outputs for the same(?) input

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

I have a function `func(x)`. I want to know the `x` for `func(x)-7=0`. Because there is no exact real answer, I thought `minimize` would be a good idea.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def func(x): # testing function which leads to the same behaviour
    return (x * 5 + x * (1 - x) * (6-3*x) * 5)

def comp(x): #  comparison function which should get zero
    return abs(((func(x)) - 7))

x0 = 0.
x_real = minimize(comp, x0) # minimize comparison function to get x

print(x_real.x)
```

The last `print` gives me  `[ 0.7851167]`. The following `print`...

```
print(comp(x_real.x))
print(comp(0.7851167))
```

...leads to different outputs:

```
[  1.31290960e-08]
6.151420706146382e-09
```

Can someone explain me this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I think i understood your question wrong. Rounding the number as you did in the print statements obviously will result in some differences (which are pretty small (around `1e-9`)).

To find all x, you should apply some global solution method or start from different intital point to find all local minimas(as seen in the plot).

The equation however has two solutions.

```
def func(x): # testing function which leads to the same behaviour
    return (x * 5 + x * (1 - x) * (6-3*x) * 5)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-0.1,1,100)
plt.plot(x, func(x)-7)
plt.plot(x, np.zeros(100))
plt.show()
```

The function:

[image]